# Why default page in IIS unable to load page in iframe?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iframe

HomePage.aspx as:
    [image]

path to Default document set in IIS as "WebPages/HomePage.aspx"

When I hit `URL` as "localhost:88" then I'm unable to get default page but get error as:
[image]

IIS structure as
MyApplication -> WebPages -> HomePage.aspx,Login.aspx

But when I hit `URL` as "localhost:88/WebPages/HomePage.aspx" then I get page successfully.

Comment: Well, you can clearly see that it tries to open `/Login.aspx`. Check the `RouteConfig.cs` in your Project (it's inside `App_Start`).

Comment: I have not set path elsewhere it is only in this html page.

Comment: Ok, if that happen again, you can flag the post as _Rude of Abusive_.

Comment: If that user has done the same thing with you more than once i.e. he's targeting you, you can mod flag it and explain the case, if this is just first time, just flag is `rude or abusive`. If you want to discuss more on this, you're welcome in [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room.

Answer (score 1):

In **Forms Authentication**, any unaunthenticated(without logged in user) request are routed to `Login.aspx` or configured page in web.config.

It is redirected to `Login.aspx` since not authenticated then the path formed by request in `iframe` doesn't find login page there.

Try after session exists for user.

If you want direct want to jump to Home.aspx from some other site seems you need **Single Sign On** rather than iframe.

Answer (score 0):

It's a path issue, I have changed `src="Login.aspx"` to `src="../WebPages/Login.aspx"` and it works fine.